# Excel writing formula via VBA

Tags: excel, vba

do you know how to write this type of Formula in Excel Cell via VBA:

```
Range("e15").Value = "=SUM(OFFSET(E6:E7;0;0))"
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use US format formulas:

```
Range("e15").Formula = "=SUM(OFFSET(E6:E7,0,0))"
```